# How to Speed up Comparison of two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two large tables in MySQL, one containing about 6,00,000 records and another containing about 90,000. I have one common field in these two tables on the basis of which I want to compare the records. I indexed both the tables on this common field but still query execution takes a very long time. Following is the query I used:

```
SELECT a.url,a.title,a.description,a.jobreferenceno,a.location,a.state,
    a.country,a.created_datetime,a.postalcode,a.company
FROM TABLE1 as a
WHERE EXISTS (
    select b.checkfield
    from TABLE2 as b where a.checkfield=b.checkfield
);
```

`checkfield` is the common column in both the tables.

Any suggestions on how to speed it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subqueries, like the `EXISTS` subquery you used here, are notoriously slow in MySQL. You should convert them to a `JOIN` if you have the chance. A `JOIN` query for your example would look like this:

```
SELECT a.url
,a.title
,a.description
,a.jobreferenceno
,a.location
,a.state
,a.country
,a.created_datetime
,a.postalcode
,a.company 
FROM TABLE1 as a 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 as b 
ON         a.checkfield = b.checkfield
```

(Note that this is not entirely the same as your original: here, any row from TABLE1 for that matches multiple rows in TABLE2 will be returned multiple times. If checkfield is unique in both tables, the result will be the same.)

That said, it is unclear how this really helps - you're not really comparing rows here, simply selecting those rows from TABLE for which there is at least one row in TABLE2 that happens to have the same value in checkfield

(at any rate, `checkfield` should be indexed in both tables to help the efficiency of these queries )

Comment: Thanks Roland. Yes, I want to select rows from table1 that match in table2. I am not sure if "checkfield" column in my tables would be unique and hence I am getting a much greater number of records than expected. Is there a way to get the results which I wanted in my original query using joins ? Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: If the join returns more rows than there are in TABLE1, then you can be sure checkfield is not unique. Of course, I cannot tell if this is Ok, you should know. To only return unique rows from TABLE1, you could add DISTINCT behind the SELECT keyword. However, it is still not clear what you want to do with the result, DISTINCT might not be appropriate if you want to somehow really compare rows from TABLE1 with TABLE2.

Comment: What i want from the result is that i want to insert the records which are present in TABLE1 as well as TABLE2 into another table on which further processing is to be done.

Comment: Deepak, there's something odd going on here. You say you want the rows that are in both tables to be inserted into another table, but the strnage thing is that TABLE2 can apparently contain more than one such row. Anyway like I said, use SELECT DISTINCT ... to get only unique rows from table1.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. Actually there was some ambiguity in the table data and hence the records were not unique. I analyzed the data and made corrections. Now the query is working just fine. Thanks a lot for your time and effort. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's faster with a join instead a subquery:

```
SELECT a.url, a.title, a.description, a.jobreferenceno, a.location, a.state, a.country, a.created_datetime, a.postalcode, a.company FROM TABLE1 as a join TABLE2 as b on a.checkfield=b.checkfield;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster :

```
SELECT a.url,a.title,a.description,a.jobreferenceno,a.location,a.state,a.country,a.created_datetime,a.postalcode,a.company
FROM TABLE1 a 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b USING (checkfield)
WHERE b.checkfield IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: yes, this is equivalent to the OP's query, but why use a `LEFT JOIN`? Because of the b.checkfield `IS NOT NULL` condition, the result will be identical to that when using a simple `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Yes, but from my experience (especially on mysql) this kind of OUTER JOIN with the filter performs faster than an inner JOIN. The OP can test it, but should be faster on large tables...

Comment: Thanx for your help aleroot. I am new to joins, can you please suggest me how would query SELECT a.url,a.title,a.description,a.jobreferenceno,a.location,a.state,a.country,a.created_datetime,a.postalcode,a.company FROM TABLE1 as a  WHERE NOT EXISTS(select b.checkfield from TABLE2 as b where a.checkfield=b.checkfield) be written using joins.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is one field in common, you can use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT a.url, a.title, a.description, a.jobreferenceno, a.location, a.state, a.country, a.created_datetime, a.postalcode, a.company FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b USING (checkfield)
```

Comment: `ON a.commonfield=b.commonfield` can be written as `USING (commonfield)`

Answer (score 0):

Inner joins produce only the set of records that match in both tables.

```
SELECT a.url,a.title,a.description,a.jobreferenceno,a.location,a.state,a.country,a.created_datetime,a.postalcode,a.company 

FROM TABLE1 as a INNER JOIN TABLE2 as b ON a.name=b.name;
```

More info - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html